# manage.py runserver no output

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I've updated python 3.7 to 3.8 and after that when I want to run `py manage.py runserver`, or any other commands which are related to manage.py, I've got no output.
[image]

I read about environment variables and here is mine, which seems fine to me.
[image]

Comment: have you tried `python manage.py runserver` this command instead of **py**

Comment: Yes I tried that too

Comment: I had two versions of python installed on the control panel, 3.7 and 3.8. So, I uninstalled the 3.7 version; after that, I faced this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the virtual environment. I think because I changed my python version, now I have to create a virtual environment first otherwise `py manage.py runserver` will not work. But, in previous version (3.7) I was able to do it without a virtual environment.

Comment: It was probably because you installed Django globally in your 3.7 install.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall python and reinstall it (globally), means before installing select add path to system variable then select custom installation and select install for all users and install. now the python command will work, no need to use only py now. and remember if you run visual code, only install system installer not user installer. after open vscode terminal and type:

```
python -m django --version
```

to see django version. then type

```
pip uninstall django
```

and enter. it will uninstall django. now exit and goto

```
C:\Users\(username)\AppData\Roaming\
```

path from file explorer and delete python folder, then goto

```
C:\Users\(username)\AppData\Local\
```

path from file explorer and delete pip folder. now run vs code as administrator and in terminal type

```
pip install django
```

it will reinstall django(make sure it's not installing in

```
C:\Users\(username)\AppData\Roaming\
```

now you can run the server globally without any problem.